# Connected sum, Euler characteristic and homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, surfaces

Given the topological connected and compact surfaces $S_1$ and $S_2$ is it true that 
$$ \chi(S_1)=\chi(S_2)=-18 \implies S_1, S_2 \mbox{ homeomorphic}?$$

I know that the converse is always true, but in this case I don't know how to proceed.

Have you any book references which explain this or any help on how to justify the correctness or not of the statement?

Comment: From a different question that you asked this hour I conclude that you consider only connected and compact surfaces *without boundary*. In that case there's the following **Hint.** Simply consult the classification of closed surfaces to find out which ones have Euler characteristic -18.

Comment: Actually "without boundaries" is not a hypothesis of the problem.